# core dns redirect domain to locally hosted server ip

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, coredns, bind9

I have locally hosted DNS server coredns 1.7.0

I have my own website hosted at ip `192.168.0.10` I wanted since I have my own dns server I wanted to be able to redirect using the coredns config file.

```
selfhosted.myserver.com:53 {
        errors
        cache 30
        forward . 192.168.0.10
        reload
    }
```

but this does not seem to work,
I tried `dig @192.168.0.4 -p 53 selfhosted.myserver.com`

and I get

->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 61614